# OpenID AX, Google and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, apache2, openid

I am trying to implemented an OpenID for our project(Zend, PHP, Apache), and hitting a weird problem. After user authenticates at the provider's side and is sent back to our website, apache gives 500 Internal Server Error response. Logs are completely blank.
I've noticed though that when using OpenID AX with Google, they returning way too large of a URL.  First I thought that this is related to the problem described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/140852/rewritten-urls-with-parameter-length-255-dont-work

But apparently htaccess that we use, never checks any files for existence, and doesn't really do regex also. As a matter of fact it's as simple as 3 lines below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (libs\/TinyMCE.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|xml|avi|flv|mov|mp3|wav)$ index.php [L]
```

Turning off AX - makes problem go away

Comment: The logs should never be empty when a 500 occurs, or the server is misconfigured. It's bound to be logged somewhere. Best check that out and see what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

I had created OpenID Auth with Zend Open ID

with the addition from

[How do I implement Direct Identity based OpenID authentication with Zend OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741345/how-do-i-implement-direct-identity-based-openid-authentication-with-zend-openid)

its 100 % working and with out using the AX at all 
example : 
http://zc.dagho.com/index/login

the only problem is : i can't ask google about user's email , name  etc :(

but regarding your problem can try to double check the `$returnTo`

and test it on other machine

hopefully it might give a clue