# How to Get User unique identification upon Gmail login using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, openid

I had implemented **oAuth Google using Zend Framework**. All i can do right now is a user is authenticating using their **gmail id and password** and after that i am displaying his google Docs. But **how to identify a user whether he is a old user or new user.**

What is the **unique Identification** Google is providing after login in our website.

Thank You

```
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oauthOptions);
if (!isset($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {
$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getRequestToken(array('scope' => implode(' ', $SCOPES))));
$approvalUrl = $consumer->getRedirectUrl(array('hd' => 'default'));
echo "<a href=\"$approvalUrl\"><H2>LOGIN WITH GOOGLE</H2></a>";
exit(0);}


if (!isset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'])) {
if (!empty($_GET) && isset($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {
    $_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])));}
}}
$accessToken = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);unset($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN']);unset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the returned ID from Google in a database and when authenticated (again) search for it. Get the Id like this:

```
$result = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
// Do a database query on your users table looking for this $identity. If exists, they're logging back in
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. This is the way when we are giving username and password directly in the adapter. But i am implementing this by using consumer keys Zend_Oauth_Consumer. With this how can i get user identification. I am updating my question.

Comment: please help me with this as it is very IMP to me.

Comment: This is to be used with open id. Full examples are in the docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.openid.html

Comment: Oh, and Google won't work with the Zend Open Auth libraries out of the box, you will need to implement your own solution, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741345/how-do-i-implement-direct-identity-based-openid-authentication-with-zend-openid